# Microsoft Access Re query after Ctrl F is used

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a button that brings up the find popup using the code:

```
 SendKeys "^f", True
```

Currently when it finds the correct record the combo boxes do not refresh. The are dependent on one another like a tree (what is displayed in the second box depends on what you select in the first) so without a refresh the correct information is not displayed and I qould like this to be automatic with the search. I have tried:

```
cb1.requery
```

after the find popup is brought up and this did not work so I am not sure where to go from here...

Comment: First off, try putting the requery code into the OnCurrent event of the form. If this doesn't work then can you post more details of the code that you're running so people will have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: where did you wrote the code SendKeys "^f",True, which event of which control. Write Me.Refresh or Me.Requery below the line or event that fires after search...

Comment: The code for the search was written in a control buttons code and I tried putting the requery after the search is called but it did not work.

As of now putting the requery in OnCurrent event of the form worked. If you copy and paste that answer in the answers section I will mark it for you.

Also could not really post any more detail of the code since the only line of code for the button is the  SendKeys "^f", True.

Thanks for the help.